# JQuery AJAX response undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-call

I have a strange (probably not for some I would wager) problem, I have a JavaScript method to call all of my ajax calls, please see below.

```
function ajaxCall(url, params) {
if (params === null) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(response) {
        return response;
    }).error(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
} else {
    var data = JSON.stringify(params);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(response) {
        return response;
    }).error(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
  }
}
```

when I call this method I get the appropriate response from the AJAX call and all looks rosy, until I return the response the call is returned undefined?

for completeness I will include my call code.

```
var call = ajaxCall(someUrl, someParams);
```

just to clarify and make sure my ramblings are understood **call** would be undefined in the above example?

Comment: You are correct. This question has been asked plenty of times, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369839/cant-return-xmlhttp-responsetext

Comment: @DCoder thank you and sorry for the repeat question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that because the ajax call is async,
$.ajax returns a Deferred Object and you can work with it to get what you need
[read on it here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Answer (score 1):

the ajax call is `async` by nature and dosent return anything. so when you do something like this

```
var call = ajaxCall(someUrl, someParams);
```

then a request is sent to the server and next lines begins to execute. without putting the value in the call variable;
also code like this

```
.success(function(response) {
        return response;
```

would do nothing as .success() takes a function or rather a callback to execute when the response is successfull so if u return something in this and put the `async` flag in the `$.ajax()` `options` to `true`. then also `nothing/undefined` will be returned.