# Why can I not see my object's properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stumped here and would love to know what I'm mising.

I was just re-writing some code and cleaning some stuff up. I have a method that does an ajax call and returns a json string. Since I use the method a couple of places I abstracted to this method here within a name space.

This is json object returned

```
{"charge_ID":"4","price":"37","description":"corporate rate"}
```

This is the abstracted method.

```
wwdb.getChargeRate = function( chargeID ){
    var rate = {}, prop;    
    $.post(baseUrl + 'dashboard_job/jx_get_charge_rate',
    {
        'charge_ID': chargeID
    },      
    function( data ){           
        for( prop in data) {
            rate[prop] = data[prop];            
        }       
    }, 
    'json'
    );
    return rate;
};
```

I thought I would just be able to assign data to rate but had to iterate through to get that to work. In fact I thought I would be able return data direct from within the function() part of $.post() method, but that didn't work. So question 1. is why can I not just return data?

But much more basic and frustrating is the fact that in the code below I cannot access the object properties. Question 2. is why?

```
$('#charge_rate_slt').change(function(){

    var t = $(this), v = $(t).val(), rate;

    console.log(wwdb.getChargeRate( v )); //returns object ok

    rate = wwdb.getChargeRate( v ); //assigns object ok

    console.log(rate); //displays in firebug as object with properties

    console.log(rate.price) //undefined

    for(p in rate)
       console.log( p ); //undefined?
});
```

Comment: Have you heard of the asynchronous nature of ajax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't return xmlhttp.responseText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369839/cant-return-xmlhttp-responsetext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember this is asynchronous -- the function has not been called when you are looking at it.
When the function returns rate the call has not finished.  If you look at the rate variable a later it will have the data.  I didn't look at the 2nd part of the code, but I expect is a similar issue.

---

To understand this issue make the following change:

```
wwdb.getChargeRate = function( chargeID ){
    var rate = {}, prop;    
    $.post(baseUrl + 'dashboard_job/jx_get_charge_rate',
    {
        'charge_ID': chargeID
    },      
    function( data ){           
        for( prop in data) {
            rate[prop] = data[prop];            
        }       
    }, 
    'json'
    );
    return { "price" : "I am not undefined" };
};
```

Now your calling function will have something to print.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. I can output the object post the ajax call no problem, I just can't access the properties.

Comment: Yes post the ajax call, but the line `return rate;` will happen before the ajax call, that is my point.

Comment: @SaminOz the objects are live, so when the code executes the object is empty but when you check it in the console the ajax request finished and the properties filled, so it seems like its working when it really isn't

Comment: @Musa and Hogan - I accept what you are saying but if that is true why can I click on the object returned at  //console log(rate) and see the three properties? Doesn't that mean that the object has been returned complete, not empty? Or is firebug outputting post the ajax call (sort of like a global) and deceiving me?

Comment: It is the 2nd thing.  It is like a global because it is in the closure of the function (that is the function has a reference to it and can change it.)  If you said `rate = { "price" : "I am not undefined" }; return rate;` in your function it would log that message and then when you clicked on it, it would be different.  Try it.